# Interactive plot for classifying data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am working with 3 matrices (Data1, Data2, Data3) where each row from each of the 3 matrices is a signal from the same time. I am attempting to have an interactive UI where the user can click if there's an abnormally or not. The code should record the answer from the toggle switch and plot the next 3 graphs until there's no more data.
I have two main issues:

When pressing the toggle button, it will stay toggled until pressed again to untoggle before pressing the next answer. It should untoggle--

The recorded answer 'Result' gets erased on every iteration and I am not sure why!

```
Results = table();
for ii = 1:10
    
    pushbuttonPlot(Data1,Data2,Data3,ii)
    waitforbuttonpress
end
```

The function is as follows:

```
function Results = pushbuttonPlot(Data1,Data2,Data3,ii)
f = figure(1);
c = uicontrol('Position',[10 60 60 22]); %left, bottom, width, height
c.String = 'JOINT!!';
c.Callback = @plotJointNext;

c2 = uicontrol('Position',[11+140 60 60 22]);
c2.String = 'NoJOINT!!';
c2.Callback = @plotNoJointNext;
waitforbuttonpress
Results =


    function  plotJointNext(src,event)

            figure(1)
            subplot(3,1,1)
            ylabel('Height (mm)')
            plot(Data1((ii),:))
            title(['AOI 1, Index # ',num2str((ii))])
            xlabel('Data Points (px)')
            
            subplot(3,1,2)
            plot(Data2((ii),:))
            ylabel('Height (mm)')
            title(['AOI 2, Index # ',num2str((ii))])            
            xlabel('Data Points (px)')
            
            subplot(3,1,3)
            plot(Data3((ii),:))
            ylabel('Height (mm)')            
            title(['AOI 3, Index # ',num2str((ii))])
            xlabel('Data Points (px)')  
            temp = 1  ;
            Results = [Results ; temp];
    
    end
    

    function  plotNoJointNext(src,event)
    
            figure(1)
            subplot(3,1,1)
            ylabel('Height (mm)')
            plot(Data1((ii),:))
            title(['AOI 1, Index # ',num2str((ii))])
            xlabel('Data Points (px)')
            
            subplot(3,1,2)
            plot(Data2((ii),:))
            ylabel('Height (mm)')
            title(['AOI 2, Index # ',num2str((ii))])         
            xlabel('Data Points (px)')
            
            subplot(3,1,3)
            plot(Data3((ii),:))
            ylabel('Height (mm)')            
            title(['AOI 3, Index # ',num2str((ii))])
            xlabel('Data Points (px)')    
            temp = 0  ;
            Results = [Results ; temp];
    
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the code working the way I wanted it to work so I made the following adjustments: the function has a ii=ii+1, so I avoid running the main function inside of the for loop. This helped as the waitforkey was not allowing for the uibutton to untoggle. The second thing is I created a global variable Results that kept count of all the times a certain button was pressed. There's probably better ways to do this but this is how I did it.